# What is the need for dynamic consensus in hyperledger projects

Tags: dynamic, hyperledger, consensus, hyperledger-sawtooth

I read hyperledger sawtooth supports dynamic consensus, mean the consensus algorithm can be changed dynamically. My question is what is the need or when it is necessary to change the consensus dynamically ?. What forces us to change the consensus dynamically ?

I read the Fabric and Sawtooth documentation. Could not find the necessity for dynamic consensus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing forces any blockchain to change consensus--you can keep the same consensus algorithm forever.

However, consensus algorithms are an active area of research. New and more efficient algorithms are being proposed. It may be that a blockchain may want to switch to a new algorithm. Or perhaps the current algorithm is not suitable.  For example, some algorithms are efficient with a few nodes (e.g., PBFT) but are O(n^2), meaning they create an exponentially increasing number of messages as nodes increase and do not scale.

Some consensus algorithms are BFT, Byzantine Fault Tolerant, meaning they withstand bad or malicious actors (nodes). Other algorithms are just CFT, Crash Fault Tolerant, meaning they can withstand a node crashing, but not a bad actor.  So one may want to change from a BFT-friendly algorithms (such as PoET SGX).

Hyperledger Sawtooth, by the way, supports PoET, RAFT, and DevMode consensus. The last is for experimental and testing use only--not production.  Soon to be added is PBFT consensus. For more detail on Sawtooth consensus, see https://github.com/danintel/sawtooth-faq/blob/master/consensus.rst